# PHP IF giving wrong results

Tags: php

I have following example where PHP IF is giving wrong results, I don't understand why?

Results are correct in these example

```
$i=0; // i is set to int 0
if( $i == 0){echo 'yes';}else{echo 'no';}echo '<br>';
result yes

$i='string'; // i is set as a string
if( $i == 'string'){echo 'yes';}else{echo 'no';}echo '<br>';
result yes
```

But results are wrong in these examples

```
$i='string'; // i is set as a string
if( $i == 0){echo 'yes';}else{echo 'no';}echo '<br>';
result yes

$i=0; // i is set to int 0
if( $i == 'string'){echo 'yes';}else{echo 'no';}echo '<br>';
result yes
```

Please suggest why this error in comparing, why PHP IF is not comparing correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Im sorry but the question this is marked to as a duplicate doesn't really answer OP's question. Anyway I can give you this: http://il.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php .  Look at the **Loose comparisons with ==**

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now I understand better.